# How to stop TinyMCE to delete the span tags?

Tags: html, tinymce

Here in my work, the previous programmer decided to use the wonderful TinyMCE on the company website.
One of the thousands of problems I'm having is:

If the original text have any `span` tag, when I press the **backspace** to delete a line (`p` tag only), all `span` tags are deleted from the text.

This error is much more specific than the other. I can delete **anything**, character or tag (including the `p` tags), using the **delete button** and nothing happens.
If I delete anything using the backspace button, nothing happens too.
But if I delete any `p` tag *(even if it was created during the editing of the text)*, using the **backspace**, all `span` tags are deleted.

I'm looking everywhere a way to solve this problem, because the client is not able to delete a row without losing all the markings of the text, which are made by CSS applied in `span` tags. E.g.,

```
<p>
   <span id="org_2" class="apoloP" onClick="myFunction(this.id);">
        TEXT
   </span>
</p>
```

Does anyone know how I can do to stop TinyMCE delete my text, beyond what is necessary?

It is not only when the original text has a `span` tag.
When the TinyMCE creates a `span` tag itself (if to underline the selected text, for example), if I delete a `p` tag, all `span` tags created also disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Despite all tell me not to use version 4 because is still in beta, was this version that solved my problem.
The bug does not occur in version 4.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should have a closer look at the tinymce setting valid_elements and valid_children. Make sure spans are valid elements and can be children to paragraphs.

Comment: Following a tip from other forums, I've tried using the commands valid_elements, valid_children, verify_html and cleanup.
But none of them at any given result.
This error is happening is much more specific than the other.
I can delete anything, character or tag, but if I delete a tag p, using the backspace, the error happens.
However, if I delete the same tag p using the delete button, nothing happens.
I'm looking everywhere a way to solve this problem, because the client is not able to delete a row without losing all the markings of the text, which are made by CSS applied in span tags.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know which version of TinyMCE that is being used. The previous programmer decided to use this library saying that would solve the problem they were having, but it never worked right. Now I'm having to fix these bugs. Last month, another developer said he updated library. But still I do not know which version or if it is the most current.

Comment: tinymce is very new, but it is still beta, make sure you are not using tinymce 4 (you will find it in the source fill, i.e. the update_history file)

Comment: Does anyone know what the fixes were to stop this bug as we are not able to upgrade to v4?