# TinyMCE not add the onClick event in the tag

Tags: onclick, tinymce

I have a function that, when you click a button, the selected text inside the box *TinyMCE* is wrapped in a `span` tag.

This is done this way:
      `var apolo = '<span id=\"' + tag + '_' + key + '\" class=\"apolo' + type + '\" onClick=\"myFunction(this.id)\">' + sel + '</span>';`
      `tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, apolo);`

The expected result is:
      
     ***`<span id="org_2" class="apoloP" onClick="myFunction(this.id);">SELECTED TEXT</span>`***
However, the result I am getting is:
      
     ***`<span id="org_2" class="apoloP">SELECTED TEXT</span>`***

The onClick event that calls my function, was simply ignored.

In **version 3.5.8** is working, but I had to move to **version 4.0b2** due to another bug that no one could solve (*[How to stop TinyMCE to delete the span tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346562/how-to-stop-tinymce-to-delete-the-span-tags)*).
In the end, all I got was out of a bug to another.

Does anyone know how I do for TinyMCE not delete my text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the setting valid_elements and have a closer look if onclick is added there as a valid attribute. I looks like this attribute gets stripped out because it is not registered as valid.

Answer (score 0):

What might help anyone who needs more information provided on this topic:

I faced the exact same issue and with some other questions/answers on stackoverflow i found, that i had to change the **config/tinyMceConfig.config** from:

```
<validElements>
<![CDATA[+a[id....-span[class|align|style],...]]>
</validElements>
```

to

```
<validElements>
<![CDATA[+a[id....-span[class|align|style|title|onclick],...]]>
</validElements>
```

But even though the attribute was shown in the editor - everytime the page was saved/published, somehow both `title` and `onclick` attributes where removed.

In **umbraco/Js/umbraco.controller.js** the following line

```
var extendedValidElements = "@[id|class|style],-div[id|dir|class|align|style],ins[datetime|cite],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],span[id|class|style]";
```

seemed to remove everything but the defined attributes.
As I changed it to

```
var extendedValidElements = "@[id|class|style],-div[id|dir|class|align|style],ins[datetime|cite],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],span[id|class|style|title|onclick]";
```

the attributes are now still there after saving/publishing.
I hope this maybe might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Could work:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // other configurations...
    cleanup: false, // Disable automatic cleanup
    custom_elements: 'a[onClick]',
});
```

or

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // other configurations...
    valid_elements: '*[*]', // Allow all elements and attributes
    valid_attributes: '*[*]' // Allow all attributes
});
```